# How to install MapServer on IIS 7.5 with windows 7 OS

Tags: web-mapping, mapserver, osgeo, asp.net, iis

I want to use the map server in my asp.net application. For that one, I need to install mapserver on IIS. I am using windows 7 with 64 bit os. I have IIS 7.5 installed on my PC.

Can any one help me to on install mapserver on IIS 7.5 with windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this [wiki page](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/Installing-Mapserver-under-IIS-7.n-with-FastCGI) could help you.

Comment: I have done all step and but working. Can you help me. I am getting the error "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981118/http-error-403-14-forbidden-the-web-server-is-configured-to-not-list-the-con)

Comment: I have all the steps but I am not getting how to run the mapserver project?

Comment: what about the previous error?

Comment: ...and [this](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/MapServer-tutorial-for-C-asp-net-td4234349.html) is a good point to start.